# Display the difference between rows in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named `Employee_audit` with following schema,

| emp_audit_id | eid | name | salary | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Daniel | 1000 | ... |
| 2 | 1 | Dani | 1000 | ... |
| 3 | 1 | Danny | 3000 | ... |

My goal is to write a SQL query which will return in following format, considering the first row also as changed value from null.

| columnName | oldValue | newValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name | null | Daniel |
| salary | null | 1000 |
| name | Daniel | Dani |
| name | Dani | Danny |
| salary | 1000 | 3000 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Finally reached to below solution

```
CREATE TABLE Employee_audit (
    emp_audit_id int,
    eid int,
  name varchar(50),
    salary int,
    department varchar(50)   
)

insert into Employee_audit (emp_audit_id, eid, name, salary,department)
values
(1, 1, 'Daniel', 1000,'ROP'),
(2, 1, 'Dani', 1000,'ROP'),
(3, 1, 'Danny', 3000,'ROP');

    with diffs as (
        select 'name' colName, emp_audit_id, eid, lag(name, 1, null) over (partition by eid order by emp_audit_id) oldValue, name newValue
        from Employee_audit
        union all
        select 'salary', emp_audit_id, eid, cast(lag(salary, 1, null) over (partition by eid order by emp_audit_id) as varchar), cast(salary as varchar) newValue
        from Employee_audit
       union all
        ...
    )
    select * 
    from diffs 
    where oldValue <> newValue or oldValue is null 
    order by emp_audit_id, eid
```

Returns:

| emp_audit_id | columnName | oldValue | newValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name | NULL | Daniel |
| 1 | salary | NULL | 1000.00 |
| 2 | name | Daniel | Dani |
| 3 | name | Dani | Danny |
| 3 | salary | 1000.00 | 3000.00 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

But the problem is, the query is very slow because to track 10 fields we have to write 10 union all.

How can I more optimize the query like in a single scan how can I do it?

Comment: I would have thought that since you select `eid` it would appear in the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option that will dynamically unpivot your data without actually using Dynamic SQL.

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
Select emp_audit_id
      ,eid
      ,[key]
      ,newValue=[value]
      ,oldvalue = lag(value) over (partition by eid,[key] order by emp_audit_id)
 From Employee_audit A
 Cross Apply ( Select [key],[value] From OpenJson( (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper  )  ) ) B
 Where [key] not in ('emp_audit_id','eid')
)
Select emp_audit_id
      ,columName = [key]
      ,oldvalue
      ,newvalue 
 From  cte
 Where newvalue<>oldvalue or oldvalue is null
```

**Returns**

```
emp_audit_id    columName   oldvalue    newvalue
1               department  NULL        ROP
1               name        NULL        Daniel
2               name        Daniel      Dani
3               name        Dani        Danny
1               salary      NULL        1000
3               salary      1000        3000
```

Comment: this answer gives an ambiguous error when there exists a column in the table named "value". I tried using B.value but it doesn't give the error but it doesn't give the answer either.

Comment: @Techie321  [Value] is called twice.  newValue and oldValue ... in the lag.  I added a column called Value in your example.  Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1c532924e5e71f201bb2276520826037

Comment: @Techie321 in this one we exclude A.[Value] from the results.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c930b8b2ebedde39e80c9b13ebf8bf1c

Comment: I was using B.value in both the places but actually column name in DB was in capital letter but I was using small case in this line " Where [key] in ('emp_audit_id','eid')"
). So It was not giving answer

Comment: @Techie321 Pleased you figured it out.  Case sensitive environments can bite you.  I could look at value vs Value a hundred times and not see the issue :)

Comment: I am  facing issue when new value is null means the field is updated to null, then in the audit I don't get desired output like  oldvalue= Daniel, newValue =null.   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=050bfa4e8285e82bd256ff3fef4a2d86

Answer (score 2):

I would use `apply`:

```
select t.emp_audit_id, v.columnName, v.newValue,
       lag(v.newValue) over (partition by eid, columnName order by emp_audit_id) as oldValue
from some_table t cross apply
     (values ('name', t.name),
             ('salary', t.salary), 
             . . .
     ) v (columnName, newValue);
```

If you need to cast the values so they are strings, that goes in the `values` clause:

```
select t.emp_audit_id, v.columnName, v.newValue,
       lag(v.newValue) over (partition by eid, ColumnName order by emp_audit_id) as oldValue
from some_table t cross apply
     (values ('name', t.name),
             ('salary', cast(t.salary as varchar(255))), 
             . . .
     ) v (columnName, newValue);
```

Comment: But this doesn't give the correct result. It provides result as follows 1,name,Daniel,null     | 
 1,salary,1000, Daniel    |   2,name,Dani,1000   |    2,salary,1000, Dani  ...

Comment: Only the first row is correct. For example The second row required result is 1,salary,1000,null. but in this method it gives 1,salary,1000, Daniel

Comment: @Techie321 . . . Yup.  The `columnName` needs to be in the `lag()`.  I updated the answer.

Comment: And you probably want to exclude rows where `oldValue = NewValue`

Comment: @Techie321 you can have a go at that yourself... just bang the current results into a CTE and add a where clause, making sure you handle the null case.

Comment: @Techie321 . . . That is *not* part of this question.  If you need that, I would suggest asking a new question.  That is actually quite a tricky requirement in SQL Server.